# How to reset a Nikon COOLPIX S800c camera?

Tags: factory-reset, locked-out, nikon-s800c

I have a [Nikon S800c](http://www.nikon.com.mx/nikon-products/product-archive/compact-digital-cameras/coolpix-s800c.html). I forgot my unlock pattern and now the camera asks for my Google account. I'm facing two problems:

- I can not set up Wi-Fi since the device is blocked. Being a camera, it has no other way of communicating other than with Wi-Fi.
- The (poorly created) manual states how to set up Wi-Fi the **first** time you use the camera. It does not mention how to do a factory reset. There are no Volume up or Volume down buttons.

If I hold the Home button the camera turns on but after which, it shows the screen where Google account credentials are to be provided.  If I turn it using the Power button I can use it as a normal (very good) camera.

How can I fully use my camera again (the Android part)?

I've talked to Nikon support who never fully understood the problem and promised an email with further instructions that never arrived. I have also looked for firmware updates but the product never got much attention and nowadays is discontinued and therefore there are no new firmware. I have tried all button combinations in order to do a factory reset.

Answer (score -1):

To do a factory reset on the Coolpix S800c Camera follow the steps:

1. Go to settings by powering on the camera
2. go to Privacy Settings
3. Finally do the Factory Data reset...

Comment: There is no way to enter Privacy Settings since Android  is not accessible